# Netsuite: How to mark a vendor bill as paid via the SOAP api?

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk

In the UI, there's a button "Make payment" on the VendorBill that creates a VendorPayment and marks the status of the VendorBill to "Paid In Full". How do I reproduce that programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Using the soap api, use the [`initialize` operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3508536.html) to transform the vendor bill to a vendor payment.  Fill in any other fields as appropriate.  The fields to pay attention to will be the [`applyList`](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2022_1/schema/other/vendorpaymentapplylist.html?mode=package) and making sure that the vendor payment is only applied to those vendor bills that you want to mark as paid.  Then, save the record using the [`add` operation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3480855.html), and that will create the vendor payment in netsuite and apply the payment towards the vendor bill.